# Order of UI events in WinRT compared to WinForms, SL and WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight, winrt-xaml

I believe I read somewhere that the order of when UI events are triggered in WinRT is arbitrary. I also believe I read that it differs from Silverlight and/or WPF, and certainly WinForms. It differs in the manner that in WinForms you can know for sure that for instance the Click event of a Button fires after GotFocus and so forth (example may not be correct). In WinRT you can not. I have done some crude testing myself, and it seems to be correct. Sometimes event X fires first, sometimes Y.

Can anyone please confirm these assumptions for me, especially with regards to Silverlight and WPF where I am not very proficient? Preferably with links to official Microsoft articles.

I believe this is an important concept to grasp, since it will affect what you can and cannot do in the event handlers - especially with regards to synchronizing with databound properties.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT is a complete redefinition of the opperational model. Don't let those words scare you though. What this means is that where ever there used to be synchronous actions, they've been turned into async actions.

What this means though, is that you are correct in assuming that one event may fire before another. With the prebuilt WinRT controls, there is not much that can be done to sync the async, but with custom code, you could implement a call and response pattern.

I blog about the Event Aggregator which allows events to be published and subscribed to from anywhere in the app:

http://developingzack.blogspot.com/2012/09/what-why-and-how-event-aggregator.html

By creating a set of events, where the original event subscriber, publishes a second event and the second events subscription publishes a third event ... to the Nth tier.

This would also be a de-coupled way to create the illusion (and operational order) of synchronous methodology.

Every Method that might take longer than 50ms to respond has been re-written as async.

Here is a fairly detailed explanation of Async from the MSDN blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/06/14/exposing-net-tasks-as-winrt-asynchronous-operations.aspx

Comment: But do you know if WinRT uses async pattern in the UI layer isolated? Is really the async pattern the reason for why the GotFocus event now not always fires before PointerPressed (again, random example)? 
PS: Your blog post was interesting in itself - I posted a comment there